# Making secure HTTPS connection

Tags: https, openssl, certificate, ca

I got a task on my Security classes. I have to generate two RSA keys (A and B), treat B as CA and then:

For key A:

1. Generate a certificate request.
2. Receive certificate from CA.
3. Use this key and the coresponding certificate in my local HTTPS server (XAMPP)

For key B:

1. Become a CA.
2. Generate a certificate for A.
3. Import this CA certificate in browser.

The result should be a nice green padlock in Chrome's address bar. However, after all this steps I've only managed to get rid of *"Entering untrusted site"* warning, but the red padlock is still there. The information says:

```
localhost
Identity not veryfied.

The identity of the server to which you are connected cannot be fully validated.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Certificate Subject Name CN or Subject Alternate Name DNSName of your certificate should match this of your XAMPP host. try setting a local entry on your client for XAMPP server ( like /etc/hosts under linux ... ), localhost is not a good hostname for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the commentary I received, I was able to successfully resolve the issue.

However, it seems that *Google Chrome* has additional security rules when compared to *Firefox*. Using *Mozilla's* browser I haven't noticed any warnings concerning my certificate.